# T SQL Split String to Rows and Columns

Tags: split

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 convert split to Rows and Columns
Input String :

SET @FieldList = 'a1~b1~c1~d1~e1|a2~b2~c2~d2~e2|~b3~c3~d3~e3|a4~~c4~d4~e4|a5~b5~c5~~e5|a"6~b<6~c>6~d&6~e''6|a©7~b$7~c%7~d*7~e7'--Input

Comment: What exactly is your question?  More details are needed for getting any answers to this, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @FieldList VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE
@Pipe CHAR(1)
,@Comma CHAR(1)
,@Pos INT
,@Pos1 INT
,@List VARCHAR(MAX)
,@BWColumn1 VARCHAR(100)
,@BWColumn2 VARCHAR(100)
,@BWColumn3 VARCHAR(100) 
,@BWColumn4 VARCHAR(100)
,@BWColumn5 VARCHAR(100)

SET @Pipe = '|'
SET @Comma='~'

SET @FieldList = 'a1~b1~c1~d1~e1|a2~b2~c2~d2~e2|~b3~c3~d3~e3|a4~~c4~d4~e4|a5~b5~c5~~e5|a"6~b<6~c>6~d&6~e''6|a©7~b$7~c%7~d*7~e7'--Input

SET @FieldList = @FieldList + '|'

IF LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FieldList))) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Pipe, @FieldList, 1)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BWSourceFields') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #BWSourceFields
END

CREATE TABLE #BWSourceFields(BWColumn1 VARCHAR(100),BWColumn2 VARCHAR(100),BWColumn3 VARCHAR(100),BWColumn4 VARCHAR(100),BWColumn5 VARCHAR(100))     

WHILE( @Pos > 0 )            
BEGIN                        
    --Fetch BWColumn1                    
    SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@FieldList, @Pos - 1)))               
    SET @Pos1 = CHARINDEX(@Comma, @List, 1)               
    SET @BWColumn1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@List, @Pos1 - 1)))            
    --Fetch BWColumn2            
    SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, ( @Pos1 + 1 ), LEN(@List) )))               
    SET @Pos1 = CHARINDEX(@Comma, @List, 1)               
    SET @BWColumn2 = LTRIM(RTRIM(NULLIF(LEFT(@List, @Pos1 - 1), '')))             
    --Fetch BWColumn3            
    SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, ( @Pos1 + 1 ), LEN(@List) )))               
    SET @Pos1 = CHARINDEX(@Comma, @List, 1)               
    SET @BWColumn3 = LTRIM(RTRIM(NULLIF(LEFT(@List, @Pos1 - 1), '')))             
    --Fetch BWColumn4            
    SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, ( @Pos1 + 1 ), LEN(@List) )))               
    SET @Pos1 = CHARINDEX(@Comma, @List, 1)               
    SET @BWColumn4 = LTRIM(RTRIM(NULLIF(LEFT(@List, @Pos1 - 1), '')))             
    --Fetch BWColumn5            
    SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, ( @Pos1 + 1 ), LEN(@List))))               
    SET @Pos1 = CHARINDEX(@Comma, @List, 1)               
    SET @BWColumn5 = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, ( @Pos1 + 1 ), LEN(@List))))  


    INSERT INTO #BWSourceFields(BWColumn1,BWColumn2,BWColumn3,BWColumn4,BWColumn5) VALUES (@BWColumn1,@BWColumn2,@BWColumn3,@BWColumn4,@BWColumn5)

    SET @FieldList = RIGHT(@FieldList, LEN(@FieldList) - @Pos)               
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Pipe, @FieldList, 1)                                     
END --End While
```

### END

SELECT * FROM #BWSourceFields